# German Schengen business visa for H1B holder with expired US visa

Tags: visas, usa, schengen, indian-citizens, germany

I am an Indian citizen working in the US on H1B with an approved I797 till May 2021. But Visa stamping on my Passport expired in Aug-2018.

I am planning to apply for a German visa (Schengen Single Entry 21 days) to attend important business meetings.
I have to be in Germany for 3 weeks and then go to India to get my US Visa stamping renewed and then come back to the US.

US --> Germany --> India -->US

Is it valid to apply for Germany Visa in this scenario?